# How do you use a string to solve a math equation using python?

Tags: python, string-parsing, python-3.4

I'm trying to make a python program which takes in a user equation, for example: "`168/24+8=11*3-16`", and tries to make both sides of the equation equal to each other by removing any 2 characters from the user input. This is what I have so far:

```
def compute(side):
    val = int(side[0])
    x= val
    y=0
    z=None

    for i in range(1, len(side)-1):
        if side[i].isdigit():
                x= (x*10)+ int(side[i])
                if x == side[i].isdigit():
                    x= int(side[i])

        else:
            op = side[i]
            if op=="+":
                val += x
            elif op == "-":
                val -= x
            elif op == "*":
                val *= x
            else:
                val /=  x



    return print(val)
```

I have edited my compute function.

```
def evaluate(e):

    side1 = ""
    side2 = ""
    equalsign = e.index("=")
    side1= e[:equalsign - 1]
    side2= e[:equalsign + 1]
    if compute (side1) == compute(side2):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def solve():

# use a for loop with in a for loop to compare all possible pairs
    pass

def main():

    e= input("Enter an equation: ")
    evaluate(e)

main()
```

For the actual `solve` function I want to test all possible pairs for each side of the equation and with every pair removed check if the equation is equal to the other side. I was thinking of using a `for` loop that said:

```
    for i in side1:
        j= [:x]+[x+1:y]+[y+1:]
        if compute(j)==compute(side2):
            val= compute(j)    
            return val
```

How should I go about doing this? I'm getting a little confused on how to really approach this program.

Comment: Can I have some set of inputs and expected outputs for this ?

Comment: lets say the user inputs the equation 168/24+8=11*3-16 the program check if one side equal the other, 15=17, since it dosent the program removes 2 characters from the user input so that both side are equal, 18/2+8=11*3-16, since 6 and 4 have been removed the equation now equals 17=17

Comment: Phew!Not so simple as I thought it was!

Answer (score 2):

Let's get to the preliminary issues.

- `e = raw_input("Enter an equation: ")  # input is fine if you are using Python3.x`
- `side1 = e[:equalsign]   #note that a[start:end] does not include a[end]`
- `side2 = e[equalsign + 1:]  # not e[:equalsign + 1]`.
- `val = int(side[0]) # not val = side[0] which will make val a string`
- In the operations part, you are doing `val += side # or -= / *= / /= .. remember side is a string`

Edits:

1. Yeah, I'm still stuck up with Python 2.7 (use `input` if Python 3)
2. To solve for the value of each side, you could simply use `eval(side1) # or eval(side2)`. There could be alternatives to using `eval`. (I am a novice myself). `eval` will also take care of PEMDAS.
3. Added edit to `side1` expression.
4. Updated with code written so far.

   ```
   def compute(side):

       return eval(side)

   def evaluate(e):

       side1, side2 = e.split('=')
       if compute(side1) == compute(side2):
           return (True, e)
       else:
           return (False, 'Not Possible')

   def solve(e):


       for i in range(len(e)):  # loop through user input
           if e[i] in '=':  # you dont want to remove the equal sign
               continue


           for j in range(i+1, len(e)):  # loop from the next index, you dont want

               if e[j] in '=':           # to remove the same char
                   continue              # you dont want to remove '=' or operators

               new_exp = e[:i] + e[i+1:j] + e[j+1:]  # e[i] and e[j] are the removed chars
               #print e[i], e[j], new_exp             # this is the new expression    

               s1, s2 = new_exp.split('=')

               try:
                   if compute(s1) == compute(s2):
                       return (True, new_exp)
               except:
                   continue
       return (False, 'not possible')

   def main():

       e= raw_input("Enter an equation: ")
       print evaluate(e.replace(' ', ''))

   main()
   ```

This is what I have come up with so far (works for your example at least).

- It assumes that operators are not to be removed

Final edit: Updated code taking into account @Chronical 's suggestions

- Removed the `try-except` block in each loop and instead just use it after calculating each side

Comment: what if the op is using python3?

Comment: I get is so my operation are being done to a string which is why Im getting a type error. I am unsure how to fix this.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yeah edited to point that out.   
   
   
@Cos You could simply set `val = int(side[0])` which will make sure that the inital value of `val` is an `int`.

Comment: @Cos Do you intend to remove 2 characters from the user input or just from side1? I'll update the main answer with what I've thought of so far based on your answer.

Comment: the 2 characters can be removed from anywhere

Comment: @Cos Can I also assume that the operators cannot be removed as well?

Comment: @Cos Updated the answer (with what I have thought of so far with using `eval` to calculate the value of a side)

Comment: Possible cases where the code will break are if the letter to be removed are the first and last. (Will update that after I wake up)

Comment: I see what u mean, I never though there would be so many issues if the operator were being removed.

Comment: I was wondering what if there was an equation entered that the only possible solution was the removal of operator not just a number?

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that does exactly what you want:

```
from itertools import combinations

def calc(term):
    try:
        return eval(term)
    except SyntaxError:
        return None

def check(e):
    sides = e.split("=")
    if len(sides) != 2:
        return False
    return calc(sides[0]) == calc(sides[1])

equation = "168/24+8 = 11*3-16".replace(" ", "")

for (a, b) in combinations(range(len(equation)), 2):
    equ = equation[:a] + equation[a+1:b] + equation[b+1:]
    if check(equ):
        print equ
```

Core tricks:

- use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) for evaluation. If you use this for anything, please be aware of the security implications of this trick.
- use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) to create all possible pairs of characters to remove
- Do not try to handle `=` too specially – just catch it in `check()`

Comment: I never used intertools and would like to do it implicitly also I think that the operator should be allowed to be removed as well, except for the equal sign that is. Any ideas?

Comment: • You *should* use itertools - that’s how you do it in Python. You can have a look at user54273's answer for how to do it manually. But remember: That’s not the pythonic way to do it. • My code already removes operators.